# How to debug blocks in Gutenberg wordpress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am building a new block for Gutenberg wordpress and when I get errors is it impossible for me to know what is wrong. Are there any steps for debugging blocks? How to get more specific information on the error?

I have react dev tools on chrome. I did a search and no information on debugging blocks for Gutenberg wordpress.

Here are the errors I get and dont know what to do with it:

```
react.js?ver=16.9.0:1233 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {icon, upload, swap, remove}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Tooltip (created by edit)
    in div (created by ToolbarGroupContainer)
    in ToolbarGroupContainer (created by ToolbarGroup)
    in ToolbarGroup (created by toolbar_Toolbar)
    in toolbar_Toolbar (created by edit)
    in bubbles_virtually_fill_Fill (created by slot_fill_Fill)
    in slot_fill_Fill (created by BlockControlsFill)
    in BlockControlsFill (created by BlockControlsFill)
    in BlockControlsFill (created by Context.Consumer)
    in IfBlockEditSelected(BlockControlsFill) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in section (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in edit (created by Edit)
    in Edit (created by WithToolbarControls(Edit))
    in WithToolbarControls(Edit) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in Unknown (created by WithDispatch(Component))
    in WithDispatch(Component)
    in Unknown (created by WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))
    in WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))) (created by WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))
    in WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))) (created by WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))
    in WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))) (created by WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))))
    in WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))) (created by WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))))
    in WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))) (created by WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))))))
    in WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))))) (created by PositioningControl(WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))))))
    in PositioningControl(WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))))) (created by WithFilters(Edit))
    in WithFilters(Edit) (created by BlockEdit)
    in BlockEdit (created by block_BlockListBlock)
    in BlockCrashBoundary (created by block_BlockListBlock)
    in div (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by block_BlockListBlock)
    in block_BlockListBlock (created by (block_BlockListBlock))
    in (block_BlockListBlock)
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))
    in WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock))
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock))))
    in AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by AddEditorBlockAttributes(AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))))
    in AddEditorBlockAttributes(AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))) (created by WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock))
    in WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock) (created by IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))
    in IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)) (created by WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock))))
    in WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock))))
    in Unknown (created by Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))))))
    in Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))))) (created by BlockList)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(RootContainer))
    in div (created by InsertionPoint)
    in InsertionPoint (created by ForwardRef(RootContainer))
    in ForwardRef(RootContainer) (created by BlockList)
    in BlockList
    in Unknown (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by CopyHandler)
    in CopyHandler (created by WithDispatch(CopyHandler))
    in WithDispatch(CopyHandler) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by ObserveTyping)
    in ObserveTyping (created by WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))
    in WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in WritingFlow (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by CopyHandler)
    in CopyHandler (created by WithDispatch(CopyHandler))
    in WithDispatch(CopyHandler) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by Typewriter)
    in Typewriter
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(Typewriter))
    in WithSelect(Typewriter) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by BlockSelectionClearer)
    in BlockSelectionClearer (created by WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer))
    in WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in VisualEditor (created by Layout)
    in div (created by EditorSkeleton)
    in div (created by EditorSkeleton)
    in div (created by EditorSkeleton)
    in EditorSkeleton (created by NavigateRegions(EditorSkeleton))
    in div (created by NavigateRegions(EditorSkeleton))
    in NavigateRegions(EditorSkeleton) (created by Layout)
    in div (created by FocusReturnProvider)
    in FocusReturnProvider (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by Editor)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by Editor)
    in BlockEditorProvider (created by WithDispatch(BlockEditorProvider))
    in WithDispatch(BlockEditorProvider)
    in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithRegistryProvider(WithDispatch(BlockEditorProvider)) (created by EditorProvider)
    in EntityProvider (created by EditorProvider)
    in EntityProvider (created by EditorProvider)
    in EditorProvider (created by WithDispatch(EditorProvider))
    in WithDispatch(EditorProvider)
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider)))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider))
    in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithRegistryProvider(WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider))) (created by Editor)
    in div (created by DropZoneProvider)
    in DropZoneProvider (created by Editor)
    in slot_fill_provider_SlotFillProvider (created by SlotFillProvider)
    in SlotFillProvider (created by Editor)
    in StrictMode (created by Editor)
    in Editor (created by WithDispatch(Editor))
    in WithDispatch(Editor)
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(Editor)))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(Editor))
    at https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.js?ver=16.9.0:1233:30
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.js?ver=16.9.0:1236:9)
    at traverseAllChildren (https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.js?ver=16.9.0:1264:10)
    at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.js?ver=16.9.0:1309:3)
    at https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/element.js?ver=a7bf20c…:884:38
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at concatChildren (https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/element.js?ver=a7bf20c…:883:28)
    at Tooltip.render (https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/components.js?ver=90861a4…:10616:92)
    at finishClassComponent (https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:17177:31)
    at updateClassComponent (https://tatifrank.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:17132:24)
(anonymous) @   react.js?ver=16.9.0:1233
traverseAllChildrenImpl @   react.js?ver=16.9.0:1236
traverseAllChildren @   react.js?ver=16.9.0:1264
forEachChildren @   react.js?ver=16.9.0:1309
(anonymous) @   element.js?ver=a7bf2…c65111e966d5592:884
concatChildren  @   element.js?ver=a7bf2…c65111e966d5592:883
render  @   components.js?ver=90…d6750cb7ae6f4:10616
finishClassComponent    @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:17177
updateClassComponent    @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:17132
beginWork$1 @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:18643
callCallback    @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:341
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:391
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:448
beginWork$$1    @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:23355
performUnitOfWork   @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:22346
workLoopSync    @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:22323
renderRoot  @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:22016
runRootCallback @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:21692
(anonymous) @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11491
unstable_runWithPriority    @   react.js?ver=16.9.0:2820
runWithPriority$2   @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11443
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl  @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11487
flushSyncCallbackQueue  @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11476
discreteUpdates$1   @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:21815
discreteUpdates @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:2357
dispatchDiscreteEvent   @   react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:6104
```

```
react_devtools_backend.js:6 The above error occurred in the <Tooltip> component:
    in Tooltip (created by edit)
    in div (created by ToolbarGroupContainer)
    in ToolbarGroupContainer (created by ToolbarGroup)
    in ToolbarGroup (created by toolbar_Toolbar)
    in toolbar_Toolbar (created by edit)
    in bubbles_virtually_fill_Fill (created by slot_fill_Fill)
    in slot_fill_Fill (created by BlockControlsFill)
    in BlockControlsFill (created by BlockControlsFill)
    in BlockControlsFill (created by Context.Consumer)
    in IfBlockEditSelected(BlockControlsFill) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in section (created by edit)
    in div (created by edit)
    in edit (created by Edit)
    in Edit (created by WithToolbarControls(Edit))
    in WithToolbarControls(Edit) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))
    in Unknown (created by WithDispatch(Component))
    in WithDispatch(Component)
    in Unknown (created by WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))
    in WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))) (created by WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))
    in WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))) (created by WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))
    in WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))) (created by WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))
    in WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))) (created by WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))))
    in WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))) (created by WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))))
    in WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))) (created by WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))))))
    in WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit)))))))))) (created by PositioningControl(WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))))))
    in PositioningControl(WithReplaceImage(WithAdvancedControls(WithAdvancedControls(WithAttributes(WithControls(WithInspectorControl(WithMultipleValidation(WithInspectorControl(WithInspectorControl(WithToolbarControls(Edit))))))))))) (created by WithFilters(Edit))
    in WithFilters(Edit) (created by BlockEdit)
    in BlockEdit (created by block_BlockListBlock)
    in BlockCrashBoundary (created by block_BlockListBlock)
    in div (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by block_BlockListBlock)
    in block_BlockListBlock (created by (block_BlockListBlock))
    in (block_BlockListBlock)
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))
    in WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock))
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock))))
    in AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by AddEditorBlockAttributes(AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))))
    in AddEditorBlockAttributes(AddEditorBlockAttributes(WithFontSettings((block_BlockListBlock)))) (created by WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock))
    in WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock) (created by IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))
    in IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)) (created by WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock))))
    in WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock))))
    in Unknown (created by Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))))))
    in Pure(WithViewportMatch(WithSelect(WithDispatch(IfCondition(WithFilters(block_BlockListBlock)))))) (created by BlockList)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(RootContainer))
    in div (created by InsertionPoint)
    in InsertionPoint (created by ForwardRef(RootContainer))
    in ForwardRef(RootContainer) (created by BlockList)
    in BlockList
    in Unknown (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by CopyHandler)
    in CopyHandler (created by WithDispatch(CopyHandler))
    in WithDispatch(CopyHandler) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by ObserveTyping)
    in ObserveTyping (created by WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping))
    in WithSafeTimeout(ObserveTyping) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in div (created by WritingFlow)
    in WritingFlow (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by CopyHandler)
    in CopyHandler (created by WithDispatch(CopyHandler))
    in WithDispatch(CopyHandler) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by Typewriter)
    in Typewriter
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(Typewriter))
    in WithSelect(Typewriter) (created by VisualEditor)
    in div (created by BlockSelectionClearer)
    in BlockSelectionClearer (created by WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer))
    in WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(BlockSelectionClearer)) (created by VisualEditor)
    in VisualEditor (created by Layout)
    in div (created by EditorSkeleton)
    in div (created by EditorSkeleton)
    in div (created by EditorSkeleton)
    in EditorSkeleton (created by NavigateRegions(EditorSkeleton))
    in div (created by NavigateRegions(EditorSkeleton))
    in NavigateRegions(EditorSkeleton) (created by Layout)
    in div (created by FocusReturnProvider)
    in FocusReturnProvider (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by Editor)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by Editor)
    in BlockEditorProvider (created by WithDispatch(BlockEditorProvider))
    in WithDispatch(BlockEditorProvider)
    in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithRegistryProvider(WithDispatch(BlockEditorProvider)) (created by EditorProvider)
    in EntityProvider (created by EditorProvider)
    in EntityProvider (created by EditorProvider)
    in EditorProvider (created by WithDispatch(EditorProvider))
    in WithDispatch(EditorProvider)
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider)))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider))
    in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithRegistryProvider(WithSelect(WithDispatch(EditorProvider))) (created by Editor)
    in div (created by DropZoneProvider)
    in DropZoneProvider (created by Editor)
    in slot_fill_provider_SlotFillProvider (created by SlotFillProvider)
    in SlotFillProvider (created by Editor)
    in StrictMode (created by Editor)
    in Editor (created by WithDispatch(Editor))
    in WithDispatch(Editor)
    in Unknown (created by WithSelect(WithDispatch(Editor)))
    in WithSelect(WithDispatch(Editor))

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, BlockCrashBoundary.
r @ react_devtools_backend.js:6
logCapturedError @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:19952
logError @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:19988
callback @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:21099
callCallback @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:13067
commitUpdateEffects @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:13106
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:13097
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:20217
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:22951
callCallback @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:341
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:391
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:448
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:22723
unstable_runWithPriority @ react.js?ver=16.9.0:2820
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11443
commitRoot @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:22552
runRootCallback @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:21692
(anonymous) @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11491
unstable_runWithPriority @ react.js?ver=16.9.0:2820
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11443
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11487
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:11476
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:21815
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:2357
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.js?ver=16.9.0:6104
```

Comment: it's tedious - but you'll get the hang of it =)

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple things for debugging in Gutenberg:

You've already installed react dev tools in your browser :)

Now within your WordPress installation (of your website), there's wp-config.php.

Add [the following to it](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/):

```
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

this will load deminified versions of WordPress core JS files.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

This will cause all php-related bugs, notices, and errors to display. Although Gutenberg is based in react and javascript, it plays quite a bit with PHP and especially useful if you're making dynamic blocks. Do not use this setting in production.

Secondly, Gutenberg is still going under some relatively quick changes, it's still relatively new, and the documentation on it isn't greatest, so check [its issue tracker on github](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/) to see if someone else has already had a similar problem; it may been fixed in a newer release of Gutenberg.

WordPress also releases [Gutenberg as a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/) and the plugin is a newer release than what is included with WordPress by default. You can install this plugin and your WordPress site will use a newer version of Gutenberg which may have a problem fixed.

Secondly, 
this appears to be a javascript error not specific to Gutenberg. It appears that you're just passing an object but the code is expecting an array to be instead but it could mean a [few different causes](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/08/20/objects-not-valid-react-child/).

I don't see the rest of the code so I can't determine that for sure or be of more help.